# Определите иерархию электроприборов.Включите некоторые в розетку.Посчитайте потребляемую мощность(передайте аргумент).Как минимум два прибора нужно

Tags: javascript

```
 function Electrical Appliance(name, power) {   
        this.name ="lampa","tv",   
        this.power = 45,1000,   
        this.is Plugged = false; 
    }




// метод, который определяет прибор как включенный в розетку
Electrical Appliance.prototype.plugIn = function () {  
    console.log(this.name + " is plugged!");   this.is Plugged = true;
    };
```

//как просуммировать ....

```
const lampa=new Electrical Appliance(45); 
const tv=new Electrical Appliance(1000);
```

//никак понять не могу,как объявить два и более приборов,включить их
и просуммировать напряжение

```
console.log(lampa,tv)
```

Comment: Это рабочий код? Я не уверен, что в названиях функций можно использовать пробелы

Comment: Еще один вопрос.. Это аля домашнее задание? Или код можно переписать с функции на класс?

Comment: Привет, Да это дз, пытаюсь разобраться и впал в ступор с этой задачей(способ не должен включать функции конструкции), перелопатил весь интернет(неделя ушла), теперь видно благодаря тебе что пропустил 2 функции

Comment: ElectricalAppliance.prototype.getPowerUsed = function() {
  return this.isPlugged ? this.power : 0;                                                                                                                                 console.log(lampa.getPowerUsed() + tv.getPowerUsed()); //насколько я понимаю если добавить еще 1 прибор он добавляется в этот код?Я в начале освоения JS оон ооочень туго идет в понимании:(

Comment: и следующая проблема поменять Функции на Класс :)

Comment: Спасибооооо тебе большоооое

Comment: Я обновил ответ, добавил вариант с классом. `//насколько я понимаю если добавить еще 1 прибор он добавляется в этот код?` - нет. Вы создаете экземпляр объекта (объекта же?) через `new`, и у него есть метод который получает его `power`, если он "plugged". Вам потом все равно придется получившиеся мощности складывать с разными устройствами. А вообще вот [телеграмм](https://t.me/CzarOfScripts), если нужно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function ElectricalAppliance(name, power) {
  this.name = name;
  this.power = power;
  this.isPlugged = false;
} // метод, который определяет прибор как включенный в розетку 

ElectricalAppliance.prototype.plugIn = function() {
  console.log(this.name + " is plugged!");
  this.isPlugged = true;
}

ElectricalAppliance.prototype.getPowerUsed = function() {
  return this.isPlugged ? this.power : 0;
}


const lampa = new ElectricalAppliance('lampa', 45);
const tv = new ElectricalAppliance('tv', 1000);

console.log(lampa.getPowerUsed() + tv.getPowerUsed());

lampa.plugIn();
console.log(lampa.getPowerUsed() + tv.getPowerUsed());

tv.plugIn();
console.log(lampa.getPowerUsed() + tv.getPowerUsed());
```

Class:

```js
class ElectricalAppliance
{
  constructor(name, power)
  {
    this.name = name;
    this.power = power;
    this.isPlugged = false;
  }
  
  plugIn()
  {
    console.log(this.name + " is plugged!");
    this.isPlugged = true;
  }
  
  getPowerUsed()
  {
    return this.isPlugged ? this.power : 0;
  }
}

const lampa = new ElectricalAppliance('lampa', 45);
const tv = new ElectricalAppliance('tv', 1000);

console.log(lampa.getPowerUsed() + tv.getPowerUsed());

lampa.plugIn();
console.log(lampa.getPowerUsed() + tv.getPowerUsed());

tv.plugIn();
console.log(lampa.getPowerUsed() + tv.getPowerUsed());
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, для вас это наверное как: учить говорить немого человека, который вылечился))

Comment: Нажмите на галочку возле ответа, если он решает ваш вопрос.